# gvim: <S-Home> skips last character on line

Tags: vim, selection, keymapping

Because I like using shift with cursor keys in insert mode to select text, I have put the following mappings in my `.gvimrc`:

```
inoremap <S-Home>   <C-O>vg0<C-G>
inoremap <S-End>    <C-O>vg$<C-G>
```

While this works perfectly in most cases, there is a problem when the cursor is located at the end of a line.

[image: before]

In that case when I use `<S-Home>`, the last character on the line is not included in the selection:

[image: after]

Complementarily, but less importantly, `<S-End>` at the end of a line selects the last character.

How can I avoid this behavior? I have the feeling that this is not specifically related to vim's "select mode", but that vim generally treats line endings different than other text editors.

Comment: Does replacing `<C-O>` with `<C-\><C-O>` solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @glts: Yes it does,thanks! What does <C-\> do?

Comment: `<C-\><C-O>` is almost the same as `<C-O>`: See the help at `:h i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to glts, this is the solution:

```
inoremap <S-Home>   <C-\><C-O>vg0<C-G>
inoremap <S-End>    <C-\><C-O>vg$<C-G>
```

According to the help at [`:h i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-special), `CTRL-\ CTRL-O` is "like `CTRL-O` but don't move the cursor". It doesn't really explain why `CTRL-O` would move the cursor, but it appears to have something to do with the cursor being "beyond the end of the line". I can't claim to understand what that means, but it kind-of supports my suspicion that vim generally treats line endings different than other text editors.

Comment: In insert mode, the cursor can be _after_ the last character of the line, but not (usually, though one can reconfigure Vim) in normal mode. That's why `<C-O>` moves it left.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Thanks for the explanation. Would it make sense then to do that reconfiguration instead of using `<C-\><C-O>`? And how would I do that?

Comment: No, for a mapping, that's just made for it. But go ahead and try if you like `:set virtualedit=onemore` (or `=all`).